# Proof that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty J^n=0$ in commutative noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

If we let $R$ be a commutative noetherian ring. Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty J^n=0$ where $J$ is the jacobson radical of $R$

Proof.

Denote $X=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty J^n=0$. Then let $XJ=Q_1\cap \ldots \cap Q_n$ be a primary decomposition of $X$. We then fix $i$.

Then if $ X \not\subset \sqrt{Q_i}$ then $J\subset \sqrt{Q_i}$ and so $J^k\subset Q_i$ for some $k$.

This then gives that either $X\subset Q_i$ or $J^k\subset Q_i$, this gives $X\subset XJ$ and applying Nakayamas Lemma gives $X=0$

My question is why is this part true? :

Then if $X\not\subset \sqrt{Q_i}$ then $J\subset \sqrt{Q_i}$

I'm sure that I am missing something simple.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yeah sorry edited it now thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's supposed to say "If $X\not\subseteq\sqrt{Q_i}$."

Since $Q_i$ is primary, $\sqrt{Q_i}$ is prime. By definition of a prime ideal, $XJ\subseteq P$ and $X\nsubseteq P$ implies $J\subseteq P$.

Comment: Cheers, I knew it was something simple, thanks